# Did Bukhari consider narrators who narrate fabricated ahadith as reliable?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith, sahih-bukhari, ilm-ar-rijal

It is well-known (among Sunni muslims) that Imam Bukhari was extremely diligent while collecting *ahadith*, and his criteria are considered among the most stringent (if not *the* most stringent) in the field of *ilm-ul-hadith*.

One of the criteria is that every narrator in the *isnad* is considered reliable.  My question in particular is about whether or not a narrator — the one who narrated to Bukhari directly or any of the previous narrators in the *isnad* — was considered reliable if he was otherwise known to narrate fabricated *ahadith*.

I'm not asking if (nor implying that) any of the *ahadith* in Bukhari's *Sahih* are in any way fabricated.  I am also not asking about whether any narrator fabricated these *ahadith* himself, nor those who transmitted a *hadith* knowing it was fabricated; such blatant fraud, when discovered, would obviously be grounds for dismissal by any reasonable standard.

I am referring particularly to the reliability of narrators who, without knowledge, continued the transmission of (or had at some point transmitted) a fabricated *hadith* from a (presumably) reliable source.

Was this concern one of the criteria used by Imam Bukhari in the compilation of his famous *Sahih*?  Or, to put it another way, are any of the narrators in Sahih Bukhari known to have inadvertently transmitted a fabricated *hadith* otherwise?

Comment: One of the conditions of being a "reliable" narrator is that s/he must be _'adl_ (or "just") which precludes fabricators and others intent on mischief from being a person of _hadith_. Reliability is not just about having a good memory. And since this condition had to apply at every level of the chain, if anyone at any level was a known fabricator, that destroyed the chain. Does this answer your question or am I missing the point?

Comment: @ansari I'm basically asking about narrators who, believing that the previous narrators were reliable, continued the transmission of a hadith that turned out to be fabricated.  Does being *'adl* mean that the narrator himself knows that all preceding narrators were also indisputably reliable (e.g. *'adl*), even for *ahadith* that were not collected in Bukhari's *Sahih*? (if so, that would be an excellent answer to my question)

Comment: @goldPseudo : I don't think that his narrators would have accepted daeef ahadith as they were from the early generation of the muslims (Tabieen- Atba Tabieen). These early generations were the best of muslims.

Answer (score -3):

> are any of the narrators in Sahih Bukhari known to have inadvertently transmitted a fabricated hadith otherwise?

The simple answer would be no.  Because nothing has been brought into light about such an event occurring.  This is because the criteria al-Bukhari used, would not allow him to accept hadith from such a person in totality.  He would've rejected the narrator all together and not consider him as reliable.